# Simulate a computed percentage based on another percentage

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make a simulator base on percent and being changed by an overall ... what is the best way to do it?

We want to simulate, for example, a swing. 20% to calculate something as a result of the list overall hitter and pitcher and determine whether or not he hits the ball. So if he hits the ball, is he made a home run, a foul ball, a hit ... etc.

Thanks

Comment: "There's a lot mot the only a random" ?!??

Comment: I am not sure how to parse "There's a lot mot the only a random..."

Comment: Sorry... I've use a translator and he didn't correct all what I've said correctly.

Comment: you need to work on the math of the problem. this has a lot of it, i'd suggest http://mathoverflow.net/ for the calculation of the probability. when the math is done you can get here for the codez if you have any questiones.

Comment: @mcabral : Thank you! Sorry for my english

Comment: This is an industry unto itself.  Your simulation could be as simple as "was the ball hit (50% chance)" to incredibly complex (pitcher vs. batter, night vs. day, weather, altitude, ballpark, game situation, umpires, inherit randomness, etc.).  My guess is that you are looking for something in between, but that range will decide (in part) your design.  There are hundreds of pitches in every game, each adding a new complexity to the model.

Comment: McKay's answer explain preaty well what I were trying to tell here. Thank you folks. But realy sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

public static T ChooseRandomOutcome<T>(Dictionary<T,int> relativeWeights)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    var total = relativeWeights.Values.Sum();
    var randomValue = rand.Next(total);
    var runningSum = 0;
    foreach (var pair in relativeWeights)
    {
        if (randomValue < pair.Value)
        {
            return pair.Key;
        }
        runningSum += pair.Value;
    }
    throw new Exception("This should never happen.");    
}
```

usage:

```
public Enum PitchOutcome
{
    Ball,
    Strike,
    Hit
}

public Enum HitOutcome
{
    PopFly,
    HomeRun,
    Single,
}

var weights = new Dictionary<PitchOutcome, int>();
weights.Add(PitchOutcome.Ball, 40);
weights.Add(PitchOutcome.Strike, 30);
weights.Add(PitchOutcome.Hit, 30);
PitchOutcome randomOutcome = ChooseRandomOutcome(weights);
// it should be a Hit 30% of the time.

if (randomOutcome == PitchOutcome.Hit)
{

    var hitWeights = new Dictionary<HitOutcome, int>();
    hitWeights.Add(HitOutcome.PopFly, 50);
    hitWeights.Add(HitOutcome.HomeRun, 5);
    hitWeights.Add(HitOutcome.Single, 45);
    HitOutcome hitResult = ChooseRandomOutcome(hitWeights);
}
```

Comment: I've try this and, for this exemple, the homerun came too many time if I compare to the MLB. Like, kind of 5x to 10x more time. And what can I do if its more that only a failure or a success. Let's say : Is it a foul ball, homerun, a catch, etc ?

Comment: @Simon I think you're going to have to be more clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @McKay : Sorry I've tried but I usualy talk french and it's hard to explain something this difficult... I've tried but looks like I've failed ...

Comment: @Simon Okay, this might be more of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Simon, now that you've edited your question, this shows the nested values for hits. You could use Math to determine the relative probabilities (a home run in this case is 30% * 5% = 1.5%), but then that just means one outcome enumeration.